# SQL INSERT fails even if the new row is in the DB?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-insert

I'm using mysqli in a PHP class.

I have this query to be executed:

```
INSERT INTO notifications (userid, content, uniq, link) VALUES (48, "[2014-07-30] Nomid has edited the post \"Somepost\"", "934512e1e9314d9c602a02a26114a625", "http://website/somepost")
```

It fails, showing the **error:**

`You have an error in your query etc. to use near '"[2014-07-30] Nomid has edited the post \"Somepost\"", "934512e1e9314d9"'`

**But if I look in the DB, the new row is present.**

The parameters are escaped using mysqli_real_escape_string():

```
$msg = $this->escape($msg);
$uniqid = $this->escape($uniqid);

$sql = "INSERT INTO notifications (userid, content, uniq, link) VALUES ($userid, \"$msg\", \"$uniqid\", \"$link\")";
// die($sql);
$this->query($sql);
```

I tried to check query execution with $mysqli->affected_rows and !$result of mysqli_query().

The fields types are

`INT (11) for userid, 
TEXT for content, 
TINYTEXT for uniq and 
TINYTEXT for link.`

All of the TEXT fields have collation "utf8_general_ci".

I didn't create the table.

**The strange thing is that if I look in the database, the query was successfully executed...**

Why is this happening?

Comment: I guess you no need to use `escape character(\) for double quotes`, if already escaped using `$this->escape($msg)`. Otherwise please try with `$msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($msg);`

Comment: Does it still fail if you do `$sql = "INSERT INTO notifications (userid, content, uniq, link) VALUES ($userid, "$msg", "$uniqid", "$link")";`? (removed the bakslashes)

Comment: The backslashes of the sql string are because the value is inserted using double quotes: "value with \"double quotes\""

The query is executed well (in the DB I can read that line), but it fails :|

$this->escape() is alias of mysqli_real_escape_string(), I wrote it in the explaination

Comment: remove the backslash it will remove that error message...

Comment: The backslashes are PHP string escaping, not the SQL one

Answer (score 0):

you sql should be like

```
$userid = $this->escape($userid);
$msg = $this->escape($msg);
$uniqid = $this->escape($uniqid);
$link = $this->escape($link);

$sql = "INSERT INTO notifications (userid, content, uniq, link) VALUES ('$userid', '$msg', '$uniqid', '$link')";
```

Comment: I also tried this and still got the same error, but the new row is still readable in the DB, that is the weird thing

Comment: The same error I got using the double quotes.

However, the query actually inserts successfully the in the db, even if there is the error.

Comment: Yes, still get the same error message, so the problem is not the quotes...

But, still the line is actually inserted in the DB.

Comment: i think your escape function is not working properly

Comment: $this->escape() is an alias of mysqli_real_escape_string()